# problema no insert usando adoconnection

Tags: delphi

Estamos fazendo uma migração do banco de dados do sistema de firebird para sql server e colocamos um adoconnection... temos uma tabela de cliente que faz um join com a tabela de cidades... o problema é que agora qndo inserimos um registro na tabela de clientes ele tenta inserir um novo registro na tabela de cidades tbm, e quando a gente exclui um cliente ele tbm exclui da tabela de cidades a cidade referente ao codigo da cidade do cliente...alguem ai ja passou por isso e pode ajudar?? vlw

Comment: É possível postar as DDL's das tabelas? Esta parecendo "Cascata".

Comment: agora AGORA n consigo postar nao, as tabelas sao bem extensas, mas é justamente isso ele esta trabalhando em cascata mesmo...tem alguma forma de resolver isso??

Comment: Tem alguma `CONSTRAINT` com `ON DELETE CASCADE `. Você tem que achar ela e colocar `ON DELETE NO ACTION`

Comment: Ou `DROP CONSTRAINT` ,

Comment: eu já olhei e etão todas desabilitadas.

Comment: ao meu ver o problema não é exatamente no banco de dados

Comment: Tem propriedade ai com o nome parecido com `DeleteRule` ?

Comment: eu fiz uns teste aqui e alterei algumas coisas e o problema do delete resolveu e consigo alterar normalmente, porem agora qndo eu tento inserir registro aparece  essa mensagem: "o aplicativo está usando um valor incorreto para a operação atual".

Comment: Isso aí é algum parâmetro que você está passando com o tipo errado para o SQL.

Comment: opa..consegui resolver, usei um programa pra migrar o banco de dados e verificando campo por campo do banco de dados notei que alguns campos estao com tipo diferentes do que devia ser ¬¬
muito obrigado pela atençao ae Junior e Robss.

Comment: Legal, posta ai como resposta como você resolveu. Pode ser que ajude outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

depois de muitos teste e ajuda do Junior e Robs70 consegui resolver.

como usei um programa para migrar a estrutura e dados verificando campo por campo das tabelas notei que alguns campos estavam diferentes do que deveria ser... foi só mudar os tipos e pronto funcionou tudo certinho o/